# Print in file using perl code but running it through cmd

Tags: windows, perl, cmd, cygwin

I am trying to print a text in one file using the below code:
test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file="testing.txt";

open(INP_FILE,'>>',$file);
    print INP_FILE "Test\n";
close(INP_FILE);
print "Text is Printed\n";
```

While running it through cygwin, I am able to print it in file. But when running the same file through cmd using below command, it does print "Printed" on console but file is not written with 'Test' text.

```
C:\Users\TD>C:\cygwin64\bin\perl.exe /home/TD/GMAT/test.pl
Printed
C:\Users\TD>
```

Basically I am just testing the functionality, later on I will run system command to take backup from my database. And I am trying to run this cmd through task scheduler to take automatic backup.

In windows task scheduler, I am opening cmd.exe and giving the argument as `/c C:\cygwin64\bin\perl.exe /home/TD/GMAT/test.pl`

This command is closing the window after running the script and I am not able to check the output from cmd console but printing the file in cygwin console.

**Let me know if there is any other method to automate the process of running the perl script through task scheduler**

Comment: I see you have named yourself *JustStarted*, presumably as a preemptive defence against criticism. But you need a *lot* more whitespace in your code, as it will help others whom you've asked for help to read what you've written, and it will also be clearer to you tomorrow when you face the same screenful of characters again! `T` isn't a good name for anything except perhaps a time variable, and `$i` is generally an array index, but certainly not a file name. Funny that the text that you *print* is proper English, like `Test` and `Printed`! You should make your program equally readable.

Comment: Oh, and I think you should change your name to something realistic, like `Pretty damn good`, otherwise you're just hiding and never growing.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for your comments, I have changed the code to make it more readable. And for my name, I am still learning (as you can see by my reputation ) it is not a defence against criticism. I accept all criticisms without any argument. Obviously I will change my name as I learn more and more. And thanks for the suggested name `pretty damn good`. haha.. I am not that good in coding to use that name. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must always `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` and check the status of every `open` call. It's also best to use lexical file handles instead of global ones. Lexical file handles are closed implicitly when the handle goes out of scope. So your code should look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $file = 'testing.txt';

{
    open my $fh,'>>', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for appending: $!};
    print $fh "Test\n";
}

print "Printed\n";
```

If you run that instead then the messages will tell you why it is going wrong

Comment: Thanks @Borodin, even after updating the code, nothing is printed in file and I cannot see any message on cmd console as well. 
`C:\Users\TD>C:\cygwin64\bin\perl.exe C:\cygwin64\home\TD\GMAT\test.pl
Printed`
Running the same script through cygwin console, 'Test' text got printed in file.